# Next JS SSR redux issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, next.js

Hi I'm using next js 13 version. I want to render the pages in server side. So I'm using getServerSideProps inside the pages.

Here my problem is initially i create a static component. It rendered in server side the SSR is working. Then I I used a api call to fetch data and pass that data as prop then also I worked.

Instead of passing data as props I used redux to store and retrieve data. Then the problem started compoennet is not rendering when i use redux to retrieve data and render component.

There is issue from redux data is retrieving but component is not rendering

can some one help me to solve this problem.

In the pages folder i have multiple components(Splited the components to small components)